# Unit of measurement (unit scale) of 2D physics in Godot?

Tags: game-physics, godot

From Unity/Box2D I remember that it is crucial to respect the 1 unit = 1 meter rule and to setup the world within reasonable values for numerical stability. For instance, [a quote from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656711/1804173):

> Box2D is a simulation framework which internally uses the MKS system of units. If you want a reliable and predictable simulation, you should express the simulation systems you create in reasonable values within this system of units. You want a box to behave like a box, a rock to behave like a rock and a ball to behave like a ball.

The [physics documentation of Godot](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html) doesn't mention anything about the underlying unit of measurement. Judging from [forum posts](https://godotengine.org/qa/12733/what-is-the-unit-of-distance-in-godot-and-can-it-be-set-to-pixels), people seem to use 1 unit = 1 pixel.

My questions are:

- Are Godot's 2D physics tuned for a certain value range?
- In case they are tuned to use pixels, what does that actually mean?

  For instance, should I avoid that I have any physical object that is less than 1 unit (because it is not relevant visually anyway). Or on the other hand if my world requires to simulate macroscopic physical effects (i.e. quite large when expressed in pixels), should I scale the world down internally for stability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's no official statement that I can find, there's a bit of information we can scrape together. You found some forum posts, and there are a few hints in the docs we can scrape together.

The [3D intro](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/3d/introduction_to_3d.html#coordinate-system) mentions:

> Godot uses the metric system for everything. 3D Physics and other areas are tuned for this, so attempting to use a different scale is usually a bad idea (unless you know what you are doing).

The [ARVRServer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_arvrserver.html#property-descriptions) docs mention:

> Most AR/VR platforms assume a scale of 1 game world unit = 1 meter in the real world.

While most games might not be AR/VR, it seems like it would be a good idea to follow this scale given no other information.

So given the 1unit=1meter scale for 3D, what should we do for 2D? The default 3D gravity is set to `9.8`, and the default 2D gravity is set to `98` (you can find this under `Project Settings > Physics > 2D`). Given that, I'd guess that 10px = 1 meter.